# magento is redirecting to magento downloader page

Tags: php, magento

I have a weird problem. We have e-commerce website powered by Magento. It was working fine yesterday.All of a sudden it started redirecting to magento downloader page which shows the magento connect page.

I veryfied my mage.php & local.xml file.Both are in their location.

For your Reference [this](http://bookdoorsteps.com) is our website.You can see it redirecting to weird page.

Our website is down.Urgent help needed.
Thank you in advance.

UPDATE :

There was a problem in index.php file.
It is still a mystery for us,how it happened but we solved it.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more information?Any recent changes done or .htaccess file modification?Try cleaning var/cache  and var/session folder? what is the permission on the index.php file? Have you set the correct DB information in the local.xml file?

Comment: It's got a 302 redirect: (`HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily`) on the page. Check your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: We solved it by replacing index.php file.Thank you